# Lazy initialization confusion

Tags: .net, vb.net, collections, ienumerable, lazy-initialization

### Scenario

I'm trying to read the resources contained in a .Net managed resource file, a ResX file.

I've designed this simple class that will serve me to store/struct a collection of resources:

```
Public Class Resource

    Public Property Name As String

    Public Property Data As Object

    Public ReadOnly Property Type As Type
        Get
            Return Data.GetType
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

So, with this function I get the resources:

```
Public Iterator Function GetResources() As IEnumerable(Of Resource)

    ' Read the ResX file.
    Using resX As New Resources.ResXResourceSet(Me.filePath1)

        ' Get the resource enumerator.
        Dim resXDictionay As IDictionaryEnumerator = resX.GetEnumerator()

        ' Iterate the resources.
        Do While resXDictionay.MoveNext()
            Yield New Resource With {.Name = CStr(resXDictionay.Key),
                                     .Data = resXDictionay.Value}
        Loop

    End Using ' resX 

End Function
```

The way to acces the resources is by a public property like this:

```
Public ReadOnly Property Resources As IEnumerable(Of Resource)
    Get
        Return GetResources()
    End Get
End Property
```

### Problem

The problem with all that is when for example the ResX file contains resources of BIG filesize then when I iterate the file like this, the memory consumption of the application increases by that filesize (and more):

```
    Dim resX As New ResXManager(".\MyResources.resx"))

    For Each res As ResXManager.Resource In resX.Resources

        Debug.WriteLine(res.Name)
        ' Debug.WriteLine(res.Type.ToString)
        ' Debug.WriteLine(res.Data.ToString)

    Next res
```

Note that in the code above `res.Data` is commented, is not used/read at all, but it increases the memory consumption when the resource is big, for example if the resource size is 50 mb then at the moment that I use the loop above the memory of the app increases a little more than 50 mb.

To avoid this issue I remember the `Lazy` type which I don't understand so much but It should not initialize the `res.Data` contents since I don't need to read/use it in the loop above, I'm right?

Then, how I could adapt the code above to return a `Lazy` list?

I've tried this way, but sure I'm missing something:

```
Public ReadOnly Property Resources As Lazy(Of Resource)
    Get
        Return New Lazy(Of Resource)(Function() GetResources())
    End Get
End Property
```

It throws a compiler error about casting, and I understand it, but I thought that `Lazy` was some kind of collection like an `IEnumerable`:

> Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of
>   WindowsApplication2.ResXManager.Resource)' to
>   'WindowsApplication2.ResXManager.Resource'

### Question

How I can do this in the right way?.

In brief, I want to have an accesible reference of `Resource.Data` but just I want avoid reading/initializing its contents (that increases memory consumption) until I really need to access/use that property.

I hope you could understand me.

Comment: By looking at the code of `ResourceSet` (the base class of `ResXResourceSet`), the **full** resources are loaded at `New Resources.ResXResourceSet(Me.filePath1)`, so there is no lazying you can do.

Comment: If you break it down and perhaps load the names and types but **not** the actual data until it was needed for something you might avoid the issue.  The problem seems to be in the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't help you very much (not my main area of expertise).. Still, I've done some looking... I think that if you use a `ResXResourceReader`, and you set `UseResXDataNodes = True` like here [When using the ResXResourceReader how can tell if the resource is an embedded file or if it is an embedded string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8158544/when-using-the-resxresourcereader-how-can-tell-if-the-resource-is-an-embedded-fi) then you should be able to load the description of the resources without loading the resources.

And then you can use the `GetValue` method to lazily load the resource, like this:

```
Dim rsxr As ResXResourceReader = New ResXResourceReader("Resource1.resx") With { .UseResXDataNodes = True }

For Each de As DictionaryEntry In rsxr
    Dim node As ResXDataNode = CType(de.Value, ResXDataNode)

    ' And then, when you need it
    Dim obj As Object = node.GetValue(DirectCast(Nothing, ITypeResolutionService))
Next
```

Note that there are two `GetValue` methods, and to pass `Nothing` to one of them, you have to `DirectCast` it.

Now... I've cooked a nearly complete example in VB.NET:

```
Public Class Resource
    Public Property Name As String

    Public Property Node As ResXDataNode

    Public ReadOnly Property Data As Object
        Get
            Return Node.GetValue(DirectCast(Nothing, ITypeResolutionService))
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Type As Type
        Get
            If (Node.FileRef Is Nothing) Then
                Return GetType(String)
            End If

            Return System.Type.GetType(Node.FileRef.TypeName)
        End Get
    End Property
End Class

Public Iterator Function GetResources() As IEnumerable(Of Resource)
    ' Read the ResX file.
    Using rsxr As ResXResourceReader = New ResXResourceReader(Me.filePath1) With {.UseResXDataNodes = True}
        For Each de As DictionaryEntry In rsxr
            Yield New Resource With {.Name = DirectCast(de.Key, String),
                                     .Node = DirectCast(de.Value, ResXDataNode)}
        Next
    End Using
End Function
```

Use it like you used it before. `Data` is loaded on demand. `Type` is calculated without loading the `Data`.